# Solution to Integral Equation and Conditions for Existence

Tags: operator-theory, integral-equations

Show that under certain circumstances, the integral equation 
$$\int_0^t (t^2-u^2)^{\alpha-1} \chi (u) du = \phi (t)$$

Possesses the solution:

$$\chi (t) = \frac{2}{\pi} \sin (\alpha \pi) \Big[ \phi (0) t^{1-2\alpha} + t \int_0^t (t^2 - u^2)^{-\alpha} \phi' (u) du \Big] $$

And determine the circumstances under which this solution will exist.

Honestly this question kind of blew me away, it was the last question of the section for a book I was working in and was significantly harder than the questions before it. For those curious, the book is Erdelyi's "Operational Calculus and Generalized Functions."

The coefficient in front of the brackets immediately reminded me of the reflection formula, so I suspect that somewhere we must get a coefficient 
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma (\alpha) \Gamma (1-\alpha)} = \frac{\sin(\alpha \pi)}{\pi}$$

Also I suspect that the circumstances under which this solution will exist are when $\alpha \in(0,1)$. My issue is deriving the formula. All of the problems before this were convolution-type integral equations and I am intended to use operational techniques to solve these, but I do not know how to tackle this problem with operational techniques. The $(t^2 - u^2)^{\alpha -1}$ is almost a convolution, and I tried factoring into the form $(t-u)^{\alpha -1} (t+u)^{\alpha -1}$ as well but it didn't seem to help. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The answer illustrates the general procedure to deal with this kind of integral equations. $\ds{\ \ul{\mbox{I leave to the OP}}\ }$ the whole discussion about the allowed values of $\ds{\alpha}$.
>  With these ideas the OP can introduce some modifications to reproduce the announced result.

\begin{align}
\phi\pars{t} & =
\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - u^{2}}^{\alpha - 1}\,\,\,\chi\pars{u}\,\dd u =
-\,\half\int_{u\ =\ 0}^{u\ =\ t}{\chi\pars{u} \over u}\,
\dd\bracks{\pars{t^{2} - u^{2}}^{\alpha}}
\\[3mm] & =
\,\mathrm{f}\pars{t} +
\half\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - u^{2}}^{\alpha}\bracks{\chi\pars{u} \over u}'
\,\dd u
\\[3mm] & \mbox{where}\
\,\mathrm{f}\pars{t} \equiv 
-\,\half\lim_{u \to t}\bracks{%
{\pars{t^{2} - u^{2}}^{\alpha} \over u}\,\chi\pars{u}} +
\half\,\chi'\pars{0}t^{2\alpha}\quad\mbox{with}\,\,\,\chi\pars{0} = 0\tag{1}
\\[8mm]
\phi'\pars{t} & =
\,\mathrm{f}'\pars{t} +
\alpha\, t
\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - u^{2}}^{\alpha - 1}\,\,
\bracks{\chi\pars{u} \over u}'\,\dd u
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
 &\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\,\phi'\pars{v}\,\dd v
\\[3mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\bracks{%
\,\mathrm{f}'\pars{v} +
\alpha\, v
\int_{0}^{v}\pars{v^{2} - u^{2}}^{\alpha - 1}\,\,
\bracks{\chi\pars{u} \over u}'\,\dd u}\,\dd v
\\[3mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\,\mathrm{f}'\pars{v}\,\dd v +
\alpha\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\,\,v
\int_{0}^{v}\pars{v^{2} - u^{2}}^{\alpha - 1}\,\,
\bracks{\chi\pars{u} \over u}'\,\dd u\,\dd v
\\[3mm] &\
\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\,\mathrm{f}'\pars{v}\,\dd v +
\alpha\int_{0}^{t}\bracks{\chi\pars{u} \over u}'\ \underbrace{%
\int_{u}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\pars{v^{2} - u^{2}}^{\alpha - 1}\,\,
v\,\dd v}_{\ds{\half\,\pi\csc\pars{\pi\alpha}}}\ \,\dd u
\end{align}

---

$$
\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\,\phi'\pars{v}\,\dd v =
\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\,\mathrm{f}'\pars{v}\,\dd v +
\half\,\pi\alpha\csc\pars{\pi\alpha}
\bracks{{\chi\pars{t} \over t} - \chi'\pars{0}}
$$
In adopting the 'simple case' $\pars{~\mbox{see}\ \pars{1}~}$
$\ds{\,\mathrm{f}\pars{t} = \half\,\chi'\pars{0}t^{2\alpha}}$  we find
$$
\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\,\mathrm{f}'\pars{v}\,\dd v
=\half\,\chi'\pars{0}\pi\alpha\csc\pars{\pi\alpha}
$$
such that
$$
\chi\pars{t} = 2\,{\sin\pars{\pi\alpha} \over \pi\alpha}\,
t\int_{0}^{t}\pars{t^{2} - v^{2}}^{-\alpha}\,\phi'\pars{v}\,\dd v
$$

Comment: Very nice. It seems that in terms of the nature of $\alpha$, it seems as though $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and of course differentiability of $\phi$ are our circumstances, although I am curious if we need square integrability of the kernel? Also, this is equation is so oddly close to Abel's equation that I am curious as to if there is a variant to solve it that way. It is literally just Abel's solution with $(t-u) \to (t^2-u^2)$ and then everything multiplied by $2t$. What do you think?